# Opensource alternative fo azure service bus and machine learning

Tags: azure, notifications, machine-learning, azureservicebus, powerbi

I am looking for a open source alternative of below services,

> Azure Service Bus
>
> Azure Machine Learning
>
> Azure Notification Hubs
>
> Power BI for Office 365 Mobile Services Cloud Services

Is there any solution which interoperates all these similar services as a whole solution?

Comment: What is your exact scenario? Are you looking to get (or create) a drop-in replacement? For on premise? Are you comparing Azure to something?

Comment: What is wrong? Please at least acknowledge it when people reply to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For Azure Machine Learning there is Mahout.
- For Power BI you might want to take a look at this post:
  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/does-anyone-know-any-good-open-source-software-for-visualizing-data-from-databas
- For the rest, not sure, but there are open source solutions that can be googled.

  I am also curious about your motives for looking for a list like this.

Comment: Thanks mike, we have decided to use Mahout and pentaho for bi solution.